# I want to set a theme for what looks Posts

Tags: github, themes, hexo, jekyll-theme

I am setting up a Git blog, and the entire content of the post is displayed on the blog screen. I want to make the post in preview form. Is there any way?

For example, I want to make the first photo look like the second photo.

[image: GitHub pages]

[image: Local pages]

Answer (score 0):

Open your [browser developer console](https://balsamiq.com/support/faqs/browserconsole/) and check:

- what HTML code has been generate for your css files (is it there, using absolute or relative paths?)
- for any error message which would indicate a missing resource (like CSS files)

That would explain why the uploaded code does not reflect your style sheets.

Check also your [Hexo settings for GitHub pages deployment](https://hexo.io/docs/github-pages)